# I need to add fields to a JSON string in PHP, but I'm having problems

Tags: php, json, string

So... I need to save a large-ish amount of data from a platform with an excruciatingly limited amount of memory.

Because of this, I'm basically storing the data on my webserver, using a php script to just write JSON to a flat file, because I'm lazy af.

I could go to the trouble of having it store the data in my mysql server, but frankly the flat file thing *should* have been trivial, but I've run up against a problem. There are several quick and dirty workarounds that would fix it, but I've been trying to fix it the "right" way (I know, I know, the right way would be to just store the data in mysql, but I actually need to be able to take the json file this produces and send it back to the platform that needs the data (In a ridiculously roundabout fashion), so it made sense to just have the php save it as a flat file in the first place. And It's already working, aside from this one issue, so I hate to reimpliment.

See... Because of the low memory on the platform I'm sending the json to my server from... I'm sending things one field at a time. Each call to the php script is only setting ONE field.

So basically what I'm doing is loading the file from disk if it exists, and running it through json_decode to get my storage object, and then the php file gets a key argument and a value argument, and if the key is something like "object1,object2", it explodes that, gets the length of the resulting array, and then stores the value in $data->$key[0]->$key[1].

Then it's saved back to disk with fwrite($file, json_encode($data));

This is all working perfectly. Except when $value is a simple string. If it's an array, it works perfectly. If it's a number, it works fine. If it's a string, I get null from json_decode. I have tried every way I can think of to force quotes on to the ends of the $value variable in the hopes of getting json_decode to recognize it. Nothing works.

I've tried setting $data->$key[0]->$key[1] = $value in cases where value is a string, and not an array or number. No dice, php just complains that I'm trying to set an object that doesn't exist. It's fine if I'm using the output of json_decode to set the field, but it simply will not accept a string on its own.

So I have no idea.

Does anyone know how I can either get json_decode to not choke on a string that's just a string, or add a new field to an existing php object without using the output of json_decode?

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing. It should be clear I'm no php guru. I've never really used arrays and objects in php, so their vagaries are not something I'm familiar with.

Solutions I'm already aware of, but would prefer to avoid, are: I could have the platform that's sending the post requests wrap single, non-numeric values with square braces, creating a single item array, but this shouldn't be necessary, as far as I'm aware, so doing this bothers me (And ends up costing me something like half a kilobyte of storage that shouldn't need to be used).

I could also change some of my json from objects to arrays in order to get php to let me add items more readily, but it seems like there should be a solution that doesn't require that, so I'd really prefer not to...

Comment: Please reduce your question to the essence.

Comment: Reliable flat file storage may in fact be much more difficult to implement than a simple relational database. Also, native json_encode/json_decode functions are not appropriate for large data sets since they load everything in memory. You should find some JSON pull parsers in [packagist.org](http://packagist.org).

Comment: Feck! I spent ALL DAY beating my head against this problem.
And then the moment I post for help I get an idea.
Just LET the php insert null into the object, and then set the value of the field to $value, now that the field exists.

This works, of course.
I'm a moron.

And loading everything into memory is not an issue on the webserver. The whole dataset is something like 50 or 60k, but that's vastly more than the platform that's sending the data can handle, believe it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I skim through your post.

And I know this works for StdClass :

```
 $yourClass->newField = $string;
```

Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, or at least, it's not been working for me. The field name is actually being read in as a variable, so I can't just statically code it like that. It would have to be $yourClass->$key[0], and php doesn't seem to like that, refusing to insert the field.

Answer (score 0):

OK so... ultimately, as succinctly as possible, the problem was this:

Assuming we have this JSON in $data:

```
{
    "key1":
    {
        "key2":["somedata","someotherdata"]
    }
}
```

And we want it to be:

```
{
    "key1":
    {
        "key2":["somedata","someotherdata"],
        "key3":"key3data"
    }
}
```

The php script has received "key=key1,key3&value=key3data" as its post data, and is initialized thusly:

```
$key = $_POST["key"];
$key = explode($key,",");

$value = $_POST["value"];
```

...which provides us with an array ($key) representing the nested json key we want to set as a field, and a variable ($value) holding the value we want to set it to.

Approach #1:

```
$data->$key[0]->$key[1] = json_decode($value);
```

...fails. It creates this JSON when we re-encode $data:

```
{
    "key1":
    {
        "key2":["somedata","someotherdata"],
        "key3":null
    }
}
```

Approach #2:

```
$data->$key[0]->$key[1] = $value;
```

...also fails. It fails to insert the field into $data at all.

But then I realized... the problem with #2 is that it won't let me set the nonexistent field, and the problem with approach #1 is that it sets the field wrong.

So all I have to do is brute force it thusly:

```
$data->$key[0]->$key[1] = json_decode($value);

if (json_decode($value) == NULL)
{
    $data->$key[0]->$key[1] = $value;
}
```

This works! Since Approach #1 has created the field (Albeit with the incorrect value), PHP now allows me to set the value of that field without complaint.

It's a very brute force sort of means of fixing the problem, and I'm sure there are better ones, if I understood PHP objects better. But this works, so at least I have my code working.